# Showing that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{2}e^{-x^{8}\sin^{2}(x)}$ does not exist.

Tags: calculus, limits

The following function turns up in quantum mechanics as an example of an element of $\mathscr{L}^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ which does not decay to zero at $\pm\infty$:
$$
f(x)
=
x^{2}e^{-x^{8}\sin^{2}(x)}
$$
Intuitively the reason is that $f(x)$ oscillates with a shorter period the larger $x$ becomes and this plays havoc with convergence. I want to show explicitly that this limit does not exist, but it has been a long time since elementary calculus and I haven't been able to get very far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take two subsequences

$$x_n = \pi n \implies f(x_n) = x_n^2\to +\infty$$

$$x_n = \pi n + \frac{\pi }{2} \implies f(x_n) = x_n^2 e^{-x_n^8} \to 0 $$

As the subsequential limits are distinct, the limit does not exist.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I had somehow blocked this basic analysis technique out of my memories!

Answer (score 4):

As showed by Ninad Munshi fine answer limit doesn't exist because we have found two different paths with limit $0$ and $\infty$.

More in general, we can obtain for the limit any other value $L\in(0,\infty)$, notably we have

$$x^{2}e^{-x^{8}\sin^{2}(x)}=e^{2\log x-x^{8}\sin^{2}(x)}$$

and by

$$x_n=2\pi n+\sqrt{\frac{2\log (2\pi n)-\log L}{(2\pi n)^8}} \to \infty$$

we have

- $\log x_n \sim \log (2\pi n)$
- $x_n^8\sim (2\pi n)^8$
- $\sin^{2}(x_n)\sim \frac{2\log (2\pi n)-\log L}{(2\pi n)^8}$

and therefore

$$2\log x_n-x_n^{8}\sin^{2}(x_n) \sim 2\log (2\pi n)-(2\pi n)^8\frac{2\log (2\pi n)-\log L}{(2\pi n)^8}=\log L$$

such that

$$x_n^{2}e^{-x_n^{8}\sin^{2}(x_n)}=e^{2\log x_n-x_n^{8}\sin^{2}(x_n)}\to L$$